Wasserstein distance of push-forward measures
Consider two measures $\mu , \nu$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Now consider a map (a priori only measurable) $f$ and the push forward measures $f_\# \mu, f_\# \nu$. Is there any relation between the Wasserstein distance (say, 1-Wasserstein) between $\mu, \nu$ and the Wasserstein distance between $f_\# \mu, f_\# \nu$? Also, is the optimal transport plan $\pi$ between $\mu$ and $\nu$ related to the optimal transport plan $\pi'$ between $f_\# \mu$ and $f_\# \nu$? I would be interested in the case where $\mu$ and $\nu$ are diffuse, but any insight is appreciated!

You can bound the Wasserstein distance of the pushforward measures if you assume $f$ satisfies a Holder condition (e.g. Lipschitz) as $W_1(f_{#} \mu, f_{#} \nu) \le CW_{1}(\mu, \nu)^{\alpha}$. I can write out the derivation in detail in an answer if you'd like. As for the optimal transport plans, the push forward coupling $\pi' = (f \times f)_{# \pi}$ will be optimal if $f$ is an isometry, but I don't think you can say much more in more general cases.

Thanks! I think I can do the derivation myself, but if you answer with the details it might be helpful for others (and I can give you the accepted answer and upvote)

Assume $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is a measurable map that is Holder continuous with constant $C > 0$ and exponent $\alpha \in (0, 1]$ meaning that
$$||f(x)-f(y)|| \le C ||x-y||^{\alpha}, \ \ \forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n$$
where the choice $\alpha = 1$ corresponds to Lipschitz continuity. Denoting by $\mathcal{B}\left( \mathbb{R}^m \right)$ the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}^m$, define the the pushforward measures
$$f_{\#}\mu(B) = \mu\left( f^{-1}(B) \right) \ \ \text{and} \ \ f_{\#}\nu(B) = \nu\left( f^{-1}(B) \right), \ \ \forall B \in \mathcal{B}\left( \mathbb{R}^m \right)$$
The $p$-Wasserstein distance between the two pushforward measures is given by
$$W_{p}(f_{\#}\mu, f_{\#}\nu) = \left( \inf_{\pi' \in \Pi(f_{\#}\mu, f_{\#}\nu)} \iint_{\mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{R}^m} ||f(x) - f(y)||^p d\pi'(f(x), f(y))\right)^{1/p}$$
Take arbitrary $\pi \in \Pi(\mu, \nu)$ and consider the pushforward coupling $\pi' = (f \times f)_{\# \pi}$ where $$(f \times f)(x, y) = ((f(x), f(y))$$
It holds that $\pi' \in \Pi\left( f_{\#}\mu, f_{\#}\nu\right)$ since for all $A, B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^m)$ we have
$$\pi' (A \times \mathbb{R}^m) = \pi \left( (f \times f)^{-1}(A \times \mathbb{R}^m) \right) = \pi(f^{-1}(A) \times \mathbb{R}^n) = \mu(f^{-1}(A)) = f_{\#}\mu(A) \\ \pi' (\mathbb{R}^m \times B) = \pi \left( (f \times f)^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^m \times B) \right) = \pi(\mathbb{R}^n \times f^{-1}(B)) = \nu(f^{-1}(B)) = f_{\#}\nu(B)$$
By the Holder condition we have $||f(x)-f(y)||^{p} \le C^{p} ||x-y||^{\alpha p}$
meaning that
$$\small \iint_{\mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{R}^m} || f(x) - f(y)||^{p} d\pi'(f(x), f(y)) = \iint_{\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n} ||f(x) - f(y)||^{p} d\pi(x, y) \\ \le C^p \iint_{\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n} ||x-y||^{\alpha p}d\pi(x, y)$$
For $\alpha \in (0, 1]$, the mapping $||x-y||^{p} \mapsto  \left( ||x-y||^{p} \right)^{\alpha}$ is concave in $[0, \infty)$ so we apply Jensen's inequality to obtain
$$ C^{p} \iint_{\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n} ||x-y||^{\alpha p}d\pi(x, y) \le C^{p} \left( \iint_{\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n} ||x-y||^{p} d\pi(x, y) \right)^{\alpha}$$
Since this is true for any coupling it is certainly true for the infimum over couplings. This, combined with the fact that the integrand is non-negative allows us to write
$$\small W_{p}(f_{\#}\mu, f_{\#}\nu)^{p} = \inf_{\pi' \in \Pi(f_{\#}\mu, f_{\#}\nu)} \iint_{\mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{R}^m} || f(x) - f(y)||^{p} d\pi'(f(x), f(y)) \\ \le C^{p} \left( \inf_{\pi \in \Pi(\mu, \nu)} \iint_{\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n} ||x-y||^{p} d\pi(x, y) \right)^{\alpha} = C^{p}W_{p}(\mu, \nu)^{p\alpha}$$
Taking the $p$-th root on each side gives us the final bound
$$W_{p}(f_{\#}\mu, f_{\#}\nu) \le C W_{p}(\mu, \nu)^{\alpha}$$
